# Does Server Core 2008 support asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, server-core

Does Server Core 2008 support asp.net? I see references online saying that it isn't supported, but they are all old references from CTPs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Answer here:
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/compare-core-installation.aspx

"ASP.NET is not available with Server Core installation option in any edition"

Answer (score 5):

Server Core 2008 does not support ASP.NET. However, Windows 2008 R2 Server Core supports .NET up to 3.5 out of the box, and since 2011-02-21 it can also run .NET 4.0 apps. To enable .NET 4.0 support, you need to install [Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c3202ce6-4056-4059-8a1b-3a9b77cdfdda&displaylang=en) and the [.NET 4.0 Standalone Installer for Server Core](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=211830).

Comment: +1 This is the most accurate answer - ASP.NET and .NET 4.0 are supported in 2008 R2 SP1. It's not painless but all the necessary parts are in the links above. There is an excellent installation guide at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753802.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, as others have said: **no.**

The longer answer: IIS is there, classic ASP is there, and other server-side languages such as PHP will work, too. [What's missing is .NET Framework, and adding it to Server Core is in the works.](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2007/06/04/iis7-on-server-core.aspx)

> Currenly the .NET Framework is not on Server Core, which means ASP.NET is currently not available.  This is something the .NET team wants to add and **we're working on adding it as soon as possible.**

Answer (score 0):

[No](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/compare-core-installation.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

With the new Server Core 2008 R2 you can run asp.net in IIS, but only up to version 3.5. 4.0 is not supported since you cant install .Net 4.0 on Server Core 2008 R2 at all.